# IE11 restart without prompts or dialogs

Tags: javascript, dialog, internet-explorer-11, prompt, restart

I have an AJAX front end, part of the front end is to automatically restart the client (reload) when a message isn't received from the server for a specific period of time.

The question is, how to disable the dialog that pops up:  "Internet Explorer has stopped working" and in the window a popup appears stating that the server IP is not responding.

What I want to occur is to restart the client interface with no dialogs or prompts.

Comment: use a timout `window.setTimeout(callbackMethod, timeInMiliSeconds)`, reset it each time you've received a message. When time-out expires do: `location.reload();`

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm doing, how the client works is not the problem, what happens when IE stops responding and needs to be restarted is.  In my client I have implemented a watchdog, which is reset everytime a message is received from the server, if the watchdog is allowed to reach 0 then the document is reloaded.  The method to reload is exactly "location.reload()"

Comment: If Internet Exporer displays a message saying that it stopped working, then something more has happened than simply not getting a reply from a server. You should look into that first, you need to prevent that from happening.

Comment: I agree, its because the client is using AJAX and the server goes away, what I'm trying to implement is an automatic recoverly of the client without prompts or dialogs.

Comment: maybe a try{}catch{} block?

Comment: Tried that, no exception or error is raised.

Comment: So something causes your web browser to crash. If you can't solve that - the actual problem - and need to restart the browser application instead, you will need to do that outside of the browser. E.g. you can create a Windows application that constantly checks if the browser is running as it should, and restarts it otherwise.

Comment: No, its not that the browser crashes, it doesn't.  The client polls the server to see if it is alive and available, if I kill the server this causes the error because the AJAX object cannot connect.  What I am trying to do is build in a robust client that attempts to restart itself to see if that will resolve the issue, all I want is the ability to handle all the errors without IE displaying dialogs.  I'm a little suprised that given all the options IE has that one of them isn't to disable prompting.

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand your issue, but to me the message "Internet Explorer has stopped working" basically means that IE *has* crashed. It only hasn't closed itself yet. At that time, it's most likely too late to do anything about the issue - it is not a Javascript error message.

Comment: Its not a crash though, if I click on the dialog acknowledging it, then it continues with the restart of IE, my script continues to run, the dialog is displayed the instant the location.reload() is called.

Comment: Solved, thank you, an exception was being thrown by the XMLHttpRespose object because the server had gone away and I hadn't implemented a try / catch clause around the send method.